# Pencil 2.0.9 opens a new firefox window instead of the software itself

Tags: software-installation, firefox

Pencil Project is being actively developed [here](https://github.com/prikhi/pencil/releases). I have firefox installed and I copied the linux package files to their respective folders. When I click application entry in menu it open firefox but no Pencil app. What is the best way to install it?

Update:- After copying the files to the system folders Evolus Pencil 2.0.9 opens a firefox window instead of the software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. There is an error of the programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested it and the same problem occurs with me (v2.0.9).

This is probably just a temporary problem. You should create a [new issue](https://github.com/prikhi/pencil/issues/new). So you can best be helped.

---

Here is a quick hack:

Open the file `/usr/bin/pencil` in an editor:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/pencil
```

and replace content with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

APP_INI="/usr/share/evolus-pencil/application.ini"
if [ -x /usr/bin/xulrunner ]; then
    /usr/bin/xulrunner "$APP_INI" "$@"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/iceweasel ]; then
    /usr/bin/iceweasel --app "$APP_INI" --no-remote "$@"
else
    /usr/bin/firefox --app "$APP_INI" --no-remote "$@"
fi
```

---

You can also build it yourself though, if you do not want to install the Firefox extension (Currently the latest version is 2.0.9):

```
wget https://github.com/prikhi/pencil/archive/v2.0.9.tar.gz
tar -xvf pencil-2.0.9.tar.gz
cd pencil-2.0.9/build
./build.sh linux
```

Start with:

```
xulrunner Outputs/Linux/application.ini
```

or

```
firefox --app Outputs/Linux/application.ini --no-remote
```

Comment: Thanks @A.B. From what I understand when building packages it won't automatically copy everything in respective system folders.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: BTW upstream already fixed the issue a few hours ago. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have reportet an error. :)

Comment: There are some more errors with v2.0.10 version. I posted up at the github. BTW Firefox version seems to be much easier to use. All I have to do is import the addon. Unless its properly packaged I don't like blatantly copying files to root system.